# System Settings for Sound and Color are freezing

Tags: release-loki, sound, color, switchboard

In my elementaryOS Loki installation, the System Settings are freezing, when I try to enter Color or Sound Settings. What could be the problem?

Comment: What are your Language & Region settings? Maybe include the output of running `locale` in Terminal and a screenshot of your Language & Region settings.

Comment: Here are my locale-settings:
`LANG=de_CH.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_CH
LC_CTYPE="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_CH.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_CH.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_CH.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_CH.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_CH.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_CH.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_CH.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_CH.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_CH.UTF-8
LC_ALL=`

Comment: Same problem ... I uninstalled and reinstalled switchboard but without success ...

Answer (score 1):

<del>There is a change that's caused by the German translation.
I would recommend testing this again in the English language,</del>

I now understand that the settings still freezed in english, so it's not a translation issue. I would recommend starting the System Settings from the terminal with debug enabled:

```
$ switchboard --debug
```

Hopefully that shows useful errors. You could then include that in your question and open issues in the specific switchboard plug repositories. (Switchboard is the System Settings application, every "page" is a "plug")

I would recommend starting with the sound plug, since that one is build and maintained by elementary OS. 
Sound plug repository: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-sound

I'm actually not sure where the code lives for that color plug, seems like it's older, not following the regular elementary OS visual style. Maybe other people know more.

Update: I understand from Adam Bieńkowski that the color plug is part of the GNOME control center.
I think that code lives here: https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-control-center
And issues should probably be reported here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org
Probably to the project "gnome-control-center" and the component "Color":
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=component%3AColor%20product%3A%22gnome-control-center%22%20
(Damn that site makes me so happy elementary OS is on Github)

Update 2: This sounds a bit like: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard/issues/53

Comment: I have tried, if it doesn't freeze, when i change the language to english. But it has no effect. I have allready reinstalled the switchboard-gcc-plug-sound and the switchboard-gcc-plug-color. It was not a success.

Comment: Could you clarify "it has no effect"?

Comment: The Systemsetting are still freezing, if i want to open the sound or color panel.

Comment: Ow! than I was wrong on that it was caused by translations. I'll update the  answer

Comment: Also, please check: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard/issues/53